# Subplot function not showing all subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

I've been trying to turn my plots into functions so I can reutilize them. Now, I'm trying to graph subplots, where each subplot graphs a category's sales over time.
In its loop form, it looks like this:

```
Categories=dfs['Category'].unique()
fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(18,10))

for j,i in zip(Equipos,range(len(Equipos))):
    df0=dfs.loc[dfs['Category']==j]
    df_aux=df0.groupby(['Date'], as_index=False).sum()
    plt.subplot(3,5,i+1)
    plt.plot( df_aux['Date'], df_aux['Sales'])

plt.show()
```

Category has 14 values, so this brings a 3x5 grid, without a graph in the last cell.
But when I turned that into a function like this one:

```
def subplots_category(cat,measure,df=dfs,w=18,h=10):
    fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(18,10))

    for j,i in zip(df[cat].unique(),range(len(cat))):
        df0=dfs.loc[dfs[cat]==j]
        df_aux=df0.groupby(['Date'], as_index=False).sum()
        plt.subplot(3,5,i+1)
        plt.plot( df_aux['Date'], df_aux[measure])

    plt.show()
```

And then input:

```
subplots_category('Category','Sales')
```

I get a 2x5 grid, with the last one not appearing (9 graphs). Any idea what could be happening?
(Simplified and translated actual code, so, if needed I can post actual code)
Thanks in advance !

Edit: After dropping NaNs, the function respects the subplot grid, but still I'm getting less graphs than supposed to.

Comment: That's intriguing... can you print the values of i and j at each iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string `'Category'` has 8 characters. You loop over the length of this string and hence get 8 subplots.

I would guess that instead you want to loop over all unique categories.

```
for i, j in enumerate(df[cat].unique()):
```

Comment: Thanks Ernest, I feel a bit dumb, that was exactly it! Do you know why my approach did work when it was not in function form? Thanks anyways ! The actual string was "Categoria" and that was why I was getting 9 graphs, never thought that would matter

Comment: In the first code from the question, you do not iterate over any string. Hence it works.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess it is based on the minimum value of your variable i.  Is the minimum value 0? If it isn't then you are starting the subplot at an offset location. If the minimum value of i is, let's say 1, then your first subplot would be like

```
subplot(3,5,2)
```

and at the second allocated subplot grid space rather than the first as desired. Also, check what your max value of i is. If you are effectively displaying 10 (9 with 1 empty) then your value of i might not be iterating to what you would expect in order to get 15 plots (14 with 1 empty).  I had a similar situation that you are running into and checking my values of i as it is iterated helped me. Hope this helps!

edit: I should note that checking the values of j would be helpful as well.

(This is also my first answer to a question, so if answer formatting is weird then I apologize)

Comment: When I check i it has a value of 13, so that's working fine. How can I check minimum value? Thanks anyways !

Comment: ````range(len(cat))```` starts with 0 anyway so I don't really think that's the issue...

Comment: Something is interfering with the iteration of your i variable, as your internal loop for plotting the subplot is only iterating to subplot 9 of 15.  As ImportanceOfBeingErnest mentions below, your loop is only iterating to the length of the variable cat, which you used the word 'Category' to fill it, thus you are only iterating over a length 8 string (effectively getting your 9 subplots) when you would need a larger one to reach the full 15 (1 empty of course). Try adjusting your variables to not iterate over the length of the cat variable.